# Не срабатывают CABasicAnimation и CAAnimationGroup

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift4

Не срабатывают анимации. circleView создано программно во viewDidLoad

```
            var animations = [CABasicAnimation]()

            let posAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
            posAnimation.duration = 1.0
            posAnimation.autoreverses = true
            posAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))]
            posAnimation.toValue = [NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))]
            animations.append(posAnimation)

            let heightAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
            heightAnimation.autoreverses = true
            heightAnimation.duration = 3.0
            heightAnimation.fromValue =  [NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))]
            heightAnimation.toValue =  [NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))]
            heightAnimation.beginTime = 5.0
            animations.append(heightAnimation)

            let group = CAAnimationGroup()
            group.duration = 9.0
            group.animations = animations
            self.circleView.layer.add(group, forKey: nil)


func increase() {
    let increaseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
    increaseAnimation.duration = 1
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)

        }) { (_) in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 4, animations: {
                self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

            })
        }

        self.decrease()
    }
    circleView.layer.add(increaseAnimation, forKey: "increase")
    CATransaction.commit()
}

func decrease() {
    let decreaseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
    // MARK: - CACurrentMediaTime() для работы вне группы.
    decreaseAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 4
    decreaseAnimation.duration = 3
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.increase()
    }

    circleView.layer.add(decreaseAnimation, forKey: "decrease")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: А какую именно хотите анимацию?

Comment: Есть круг, анимация начинается с увеличения размера круга, потом остановка и по истечению 5 секунд уменьшение к изначальному размеру в течении 3 сек

Comment: Круг создан программно во вьюдидлоаде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с `UIView.animate` не нужны `CATransaction` и прочее. Пример зацикленной анимации:

```
func animateCircleIncrease() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    }) { isCompleted in
        if isCompleted {
            self.animateCircleDecrease()
        }
    }
}

func animateCircleDecrease() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 5, animations: {
        self.circleView.transform = .identity
    }, completion: { isCompleted in
        if isCompleted {
            self.animateCircleIncrease()
        }
    })
}
```

И для отмены анимации:

```
circleView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Все анимации удалятся и `UIView` сразу возвратится в исходный вид.

---

Можете добавить к каждой анимации в группу анимацию радиуса скругления. Либо сделать намного проще с `CGAffineTransform`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
}) { (_) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 5, animations: {
        self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}
```

---

Странно ведет себя подробный сценарий при наличии beginTime. Поэтому предлагаю из группы анимаций преобразовать в цепочку анимаций:

```
let maxSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
let minSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

// MARK: - вызываете в нужный момент:
func increase() {
    let increaseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
    increaseAnimation.duration = 1
    increaseAnimation.fromValue = circleView.bounds.size
    increaseAnimation.toValue = maxSize
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.circleView.bounds.size = self.maxSize
        // MARK: - после завершения анимации увеличения вызываем анимацию уменьшения.
        self.decrease()
    }
    circleView.layer.add(increaseAnimation, forKey: "increase")
    CATransaction.commit()
}

func decrease() {
    let decreaseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
    // MARK: - CACurrentMediaTime() для работы вне группы.
    decreaseAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5
    decreaseAnimation.duration = 3
    decreaseAnimation.fromValue = circleView.bounds.size
    decreaseAnimation.toValue = minSize
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.circleView.bounds.size = self.minSize
    }
    circleView.layer.add(decreaseAnimation, forKey: "decrease")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: Теперь отлично, все работает по времени как надо, увеличивается и уменьшается в нужный момент. Но теперь анимация происходит не как увеличение/уменьшение круга, а как увелич/уменьш квадрата с закругленными краями, радиус круга прописан так circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * circleView.bounds.size.width. А когда его ставлю circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 75 и150 в начале анимации и конце соответсвенно (половины от диаметра круга) то в конце увеличения образуется круг, но анимация происходит с увеличением фигуры непонятной формы. И так же уменьшение непонятное. Не могу настроить

Comment: Извиняюсь, а могли бы подсказать как остановить полностью эту анимацию и вернуть все в первоначальный размер? Спасибо

Comment: @ArturSkachkov немного не понял вопрос. self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity вощвращает к исходному размеру. Или в плане прервать?

Comment: Да, именно прервать все анимации. У меня при нажатии кнопки старт срабатывает increase(). Пример increase() и decrease() добавил вышел в вопрос. Но у себя я еще в decrease 
setCompletionBlock добавил increase() - те зациклил на постоянное выполнение этой анимации. Но на кнопку стоп нужно полностью останавливать эту анимацию.

Comment: @ArturSkachkov , обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огроменное!